# Safely extending functionality of a standard library class

Tags: ruby

Is there a simple way to extend a functionality of a standard library class like `String` inside a module without affecting anything outside of it? Example (won't work):

```
module Foo
  class String
    def hello
      "hello #{self}!"
    end
  end

  class Bar
    def greet name
      name.hello
    end
  end
end
```

Result I'm looking for:

```
Foo::Bar.new.greet 'Tom' #=> hello Tom!
'Tom'.hello #=> NoMethodError
```

I'm aware of solutions like creating `MyString < String` with desired functionality, but I would rather not call `MyString.new('foo')` every time I want to use a string inside the module.

I realise this may not be considered good practice, I'm just looking to expand my understanding of the language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're looking for is [Refinement](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/doc/syntax/refinements_rdoc.html):

> Refinements are designed to reduce the impact of monkey patching on
>   other users of the monkey-patched class. ***Refinements provide a way to
>   extend a class locally***.

```
module Foo
  refine String do
    def hello
      "hello #{self}!"
    end
  end
end

puts 'Tom'.hello
#=> undefined method `hello' for "Tom":String
using Foo
puts 'Tom'.hello
#=> hello Tom!
```

Using refinement inside `Bar` class:

```
# Without refinement
class Bar
  def greet(name)
    name.hello
  end
end

puts Bar.new.greet('Tom')
#=> undefined method `hello' for "Tom":String

# With refinement
class Bar
  using Foo
  def greet(name)
    name.hello
  end
end

puts Bar.new.greet('Tom')
#=> hello Tom!
```

For the complete info about scoping, method lookup and stuff look into docs link I've provided :)

P.S. Be aware, that Rubinius developers are philosophically opposed to Refinements and thus will never implement them (c) Jörg W Mittag.

Comment: Yes, I am pretty sure he wants refinements and this is not a misunderstanding.

Comment: Perhaps, provide a small snippet of code illustrating how refinements could be used here?

Comment: Yes, a typo of course. A snippet refining the `String` class would be most welcome

Comment: One thing to mention is that the Rubinius developers are philosophically opposed to Refinements and thus will never implement them. JRuby OTOH has them.

Comment: Thanks! One thing worth noting is that `using` seems to be working only in a "file" scope, meaning it cannot be nested inside a class like you did in the second example. From what I read they changed it right before release and didn't update the docs.

Comment: @PiotrKruczek both my examples were tested with Ruby 2.3.1, and they work. So I am pretty sure it's fine to use `using` inside class.

Comment: You're correct. That's how it was in Ruby 2.0.0. Thanks!

Comment: @PiotrKruczek: Refinements are still in a state of flux. They used to be very broad, when they were first tried out, then they were very restricted when they were released (only allowed to be used in script scope, with `using` only being defined as a singleton method on `main`), now they are being expanded again, and can also be used at module scope (`Module#using`).

Answer (score 0):

Write a class of the same name then use `require_relative` (or similar method) to include it.

```
class Date
    def itis
        puts "It is " + self.to_s
    end
```

Example:

```
[1] pry(main)> require_relative 'date.rb'
=> true
[2] pry(main)> require 'date'
=> true
[3] pry(main)> Date.new(2018, 10, 9).itis
It is 2018-10-09
=> nil
```